# Clojure: How to ignore exceptions that may be thrown from an expression?

Tags: clojure

I use `(try (/ 1 0) (catch Exception e))` but it seems redundant. Is there an easier way to do this?
An example where I'm use this is that I do `sql/drop-table`. It doesn't matter if that call fails because the table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about writing a macro like this:

```
(defmacro swallow-exceptions [& body]
    `(try ~@body (catch Exception e#)))

(swallow-exceptions (/ 1 0)) ; nil
```

More sophisticated examples are [in this post](http://bitumenframework.blogspot.fi/2011/01/non-breaking-error-handling-in-clojure.html).

Comment: If the value of the swallow-exceptions expression is used in further calculation, you will want to make sure a reasonable default is used.  What is "reasonable" will vary depending on the context.  It's trivial to extend the macro to return a supplied default in case of exception, but it's something to keep in mind.